# .htaccess check if rewrite subdirectory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to point each subdomain to a corresponding directory by default. To make things simple subdomain and directoryname are the same. This works well but is there any way to check if the actual directory exists? If not I  don't want to do the rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ %1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: @anubhava it is version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %1/index.php [L]
```

This will rewrite to a `subdomain.example.com/foobar` to `subdomain.example.com/subdomain/index.php` only if `subdomain` directory exists with a `index.php` file in it.

Comment: Let me know if there is any question/doubt about it.